# How to search exact number in php

Tags: php, mysql, search

**how to search exact number**

this code is working like this

if i search 24626838(this is complete no) it is showing nothing

after that if i search this no 2462683(this is not complete no)

so it is showing result like this

like this

```
24626838
24626838
24626836
24626832
24626837
```

and i want  a result like that

if i search this no 24626838 (this is complete no)

so it is showing exact like this

```
24626838
24626838
```

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue

**and this is code**

```
<?php

    //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('member');

$alphabet = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'); 
foreach ($alphabet as $letter) { 
echo "<a href=\"viewuser.php?letter=" . $letter . "\" class=\"style2\">" . $letter . "</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;"; 

} 


echo "<br>";
echo "<a href=\"index.php?\" class=\"style2\">Show All</a></p><br /> <form method=\"post\" action=\"?\">

        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"letter\" value=\"{$_GET['letter']}\" />";


$page = (empty($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$letter = (empty($_GET['letter'])) ? "%" : $_GET['letter'];
$name = (empty($_GET['name'])) ? "%male" : $_GET['name'];
?></td>
            </tr>

            <p> 
              <?php

//get date
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];

$s = $_GET['s'];
if (!$s)

$s = 0;
$e = 12;

$next = $s + $e; $prev = $s - $e;
    if (strlen($search)<=1)
   echo "";

    else
   {
     echo "<class=\"style2\"> You searched for <b>$search</b>";

     //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('member');



 //explode search term
           $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);
           foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($search_each, 0, 9));
    //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1) $construct .= "number LIKE '$str%'";

}




        //echo out construct

  $construct = "SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE $construct";

    $run = mysql_query($construct);
     $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
       if ($foundnum==0)
        echo "<class=\"style2\">No user found.";
     else
     {






 ?>






<?php

 echo "<class=\"style2\"><p>$foundnum results found.</p>";

       while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
              {
echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>User name</th><th>Number</th><th>Exchange</th><th>Cabnint</th><th>Service</th><th>Open Date</th><th>Close Date</th><th>Remaks</th><th>Status</th><th>Edit</th><th>Detail</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";

if ($runrows > 0) {
        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
             echo $runrows['username'];
            echo "</td><td>";
                echo $runrows['number'];
                echo "</td><td>";
            echo $runrows['exchange'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['cabnint'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['service'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['opendate'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['closedate'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['remaks'];
                echo "</td><td>";
        echo $runrows['status'];
                echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="edit.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Edit</a>';
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="detail.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Detail</a>';
        echo "</td><td>";
            echo '<a href="delete.php?id=' . $runrows['id'] . '" class="style2">Delete</a>';
                echo "</td></tr>";

        }
} else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
       }

     }



    }
?>
```

Comment: If you want exact results use the equals operator

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for an exact number, use `column='$number'` instead of `column LIKE $number`. In the `WHERE` clause, I'd suggest to enclose even numbers in single quotes, because I recently encountered the problem that using `WHERE column = 1234` this also matches `12345`, but `WHERE column = '1234'` matches the very exact number only.

Comment: Your recent encounter is wrong. `=` does an exact match with or without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
number LIKE '$str%'
```

Don't use that way. Instead, try giving this way:

```
number = '$str'
```

So that it performs a strict `SELECT` instead of search. When you give a `%`, it might expect something else to be present (or not, I am not sure about this).

Also, it is not a good idea to use `LIKE` for numbers. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: What is the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

It should work try this

```
 if ($x==1) $construct .= "number LIKE '".$str."%'";
```

Comment: `$construct = "SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE $construct";` after this line add `echo $construct` and give me the result of that echo so that we can check